# connect postgres fron docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have postgres installed in my ubuntu18.04, and running on port 5432.

[image]

I have django application and its in docker.

my database connection in `settings.py` file is like below.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

when i run command `sudo docker-compose run` it gives me below error.

[image]

Comment: change your connection file for host details..give machine IP instead of 127.0.0.1 and make sure your machine IP with 5432 is accessible.

Comment: @BhagyashriMachale, its works, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` in your Django application refers to localhost in the Docker container, not your host machine.

Get the IP of your Ubuntu host, e.g. by running `ifconfig`, and configure your Django application to use that IP.